# How do I display current timezone and full datetime in two different TextView?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I want to display timezone as

```
Current Timezone is: Indian Standard Time (IST) (GMT +05:30)
```

and datetime as

```
Wednesday, 18-March-2015, 09:07:12 pm
```

and time 2nd TextView (datetime) should be updating every second.

I am creating date time as

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

and timezone as

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
current_Time_Zone = (TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID()).getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));
currentTimeZone.setText("Current Timezone: " + current_Time_Zone);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textcreation itself shouldn't be a problem. For the update: use a Timer like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer(true);
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateTime();
        }
    }, new Date() , 1000l);
```

This will update the Time every second, starting from the timercreation.

Comment: How do I display timezone ?

`Indian Standard Time (IST) (GMT +05:30)`

I need the correct format string.. Currently I'm using 
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy - h:mm:s a", Locale.US);`

Comment: Finally got exact string, @paul, here is android documentation reference -  [link]http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: zzzz (zzz) \'( GMT + 05:30)\' should be the right format